# What is the right SciPy sparse matrix format for incremental summation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, scientific-computing

In my code I am currently iterating and creating three lists:

`data, row, col`

There is a high repetition of `(row, col)` pairs, and in my final sparse matrix `M` I would like the value of `M[row, col]` to be the sum of all the corresponding elements in `data`. From reading the documentation, the [`coo_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix) format seems perfect and for small examples it works just fine.

The problem I am having is that when I scale up my problem size, it looks like the intermediate lists `data, row, col` are using up all of my (8gb) of memory and the swap space and my script gets automatically killed.

So my question is:

Is there an appropriate format or an efficient way of incrementally building my summed matrix so I don't have to store the full intermediate lists / numpy arrays?

My program loops over a grid, creating `local_data, local_row, local_col` lists at each point, the elements of which are then appended to `data, row, col`, so being able to update the sparse matrix with lists as per the sparse matrix constructors would be the ideal case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that may be killing you: the duplicates or the overhead of a list over an array. In either case, probably the right thing to do is to grow your list only so big before dumping it into a `coo_matrix` and adding it to your total. I took a couple of timings:

```
rows = list(np.random.randint(100, size=(10000,)))
cols = list(np.random.randint(100, size=(10000,)))
values = list(np.random.rand(10000))

%timeit sps.coo_matrix((values, (rows, cols)))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.03 ms per loop

%timeit (sps.coo_matrix((values[:5000], (rows[:5000], cols[:5000]))) +
         sps.coo_matrix((values[5000:], (rows[5000:], cols[5000:]))))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.24 ms per loop

%timeit sps.coo_matrix((values[:5000], (rows[:5000], cols[:5000])))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.16 ms per loop
```

So there is about a 25% overhead in splitting the lists in two, converting each to a `coo_matrix` and then adding them together. And it doesn't seem to be as bad if you do more splits:

```
%timeit (sps.coo_matrix((values[:2500], (rows[:2500], cols[:2500]))) +   
         sps.coo_matrix((values[2500:5000], (rows[2500:5000], cols[2500:5000]))) +  
         sps.coo_matrix((values[5000:7500], (rows[5000:7500], cols[5000:7500]))) + 
         sps.coo_matrix((values[7500:], (rows[7500:], cols[7500:]))))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.76 ms per loop
```

Comment: Jaime - thanks once again. I'm now using the "growing the list only so big" approach  and (at least this part of) my code runs in a reasonable time without crashing.